# Timeline request function for Twitter bot

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, twitter

I'm writing a Twitter™ bot for the [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) site using JavaScript. To ensure that it doesn't tweet about the same question twice in a row, I request the account's timeline. My code should work, but I have a feeling that there's something "wrong" with the way I've written it.

The `get_request` function is a wrapper for `XMLHttpRequest` that returns a Promise object. It takes one `url` parameter, and an optional `responsetype` parameter that is currently unused by `get_twitter_timeline_fragments`. The `get_twitter_timeline_fragments` function is initially called with only the `userid` and `count` parameters, as `maxid` and `fragments` are used internally. The function doesn't call itself recursively because of the behaviour of `Promise`.

Here is the `get_twitter_timeline_fragments` function:

```
function get_twitter_timeline_fragments(userid, count, maxid, fragments) {
    if (fragments === undefined) {
        fragments = [];
    }
    return get_request(
        "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=" + userid +
        "&count=" + ((count > 200) ? 200 : count) +
        ((maxid === undefined) ? "" : ("&max_id=" + maxid))
    ).then(function(response) {
        qobj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        fragments.concat(qobj);
        if (qobj.length >= count) {
            return fragments;
        } else {
            return get_twitter_timeline_fragments(userid, count - qobj.length, qobj[qobj.length - 1].id_str, fragments);
        }
    });
}
```

To use the result of the function would require `get_twitter_timeline_fragments(userid, count).then(f)` where `f=x=>isPromise(x)?x.then(f):x`; that doesn't seem like a big problem because I'm going to wrap this function in one that processes the data.

The full code is located [here](https://github.com/wizzwizz4/retrostack-birdsong/blob/master/bot.js). To run the code on the test page you must "Allow All" on your ad-blocker, use a "Same Origin" spoofer (e.g. CORS everywhere) and pre-authenticate to the Twitter API with an API key (so the Twitter side works).